# Is there a way to open a pdf automatically in a specific page?

Tags: pdf

I read pdf-books and wanted to ask if there is a way to automatically open them in a specific page (so as not to have to navigate to the last page I read every single time).

Thanks.

note: I use adobe reader X, but if there is a better solution in another free program, please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Screenshots from Adobe Reader 9)

You can set Adobe Reader to always restore the last view, which includes the last page, when opening documents:

1. Open the preferences window (`Edit` => `Preferences`).
2. Go to the Documents category on the left.
3. Tick `Restore last view settings when reopening documents`.

[[image: Screenshot of preferences window]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1Cg.png)

Comment: unfortunatly, this doesn't work.

Comment: @jonatr It doesn't? It always works for me... It saves the opened page on (successful) close (crash does not count). The next time that particular document is opened, it's always to the same location from the previous close/save. It's the standard method for doing this in Adobe Reader: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9534/adobe-reader-restore-last-viewed-page-when-opening-documents/

Comment: I can't get to the bottom of this - it didn't work on one computer and did work on the other.

Comment: @jonatr Are they exactly the same version (`Help` => `About Adobe Reader X`, version number down at the bottom)? Do you know if any other settings have been changed, plugins installed, etc.?

Comment: both exactly the same as far as I can tell (regarding the adobe reader anyhow). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a bookmark plugin for Adobe Reader X, there are a lot of them. Check this page: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bookmark-page-pdf-document-open-adobe-reader/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, and I implemented it. It's useful especially for multiple bookmarks. Downside is that it doesn't launch on file opening and secondly that it's not saved on the file, and when the file is moved the bookmarks aren't moved with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `evince` myself, pdf automatically open at the last page I was reading last time I opened them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Skim.app](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) (on MacOS X) which lets me save bookmarks that point to a certain page in a pdf file.